# Can I get rid of the noise in my differential equation solution?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, symbolic, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy

I am solving a differential equation:

```
c = 0.01333;
Ang[x_] := -I Log[-Exp[I x]]/2;
y[x_, t_] = DSolveValue[
{u''[t] + (4 (c t - Cos[x])^2 + 4 Sin[x]^2 + I 2 c) u[t] == 0,
u'[0] == I 2 Cos[x] Cos[Ang[x]] - I 2 Sin[x] Sin[Ang[x]],
u[0] == Cos[Ang[x]]},
u[t], t];
```

My issue is that the plots of `Re[y[x,t]]` for a specific `t` and `-Pi<=x<=Pi` show significant noise. Is there any way to get rid of it, or solve the equation in a different way so that this does not occur?

An example plot showing `Re[y[x,100]]`:
[image]

The solution is an even function with maximal and minimal values of +1 and -1, whereas the plot clearly shows "random" spikes.

Comment: Can you please post an example plot? It's possible that we'd be able to clear up the problem without even having to run the code.

Comment: @march, thanks for the suggestion. I have edited the question to include a plot.

Comment: I tried to plot those function, and `Plot` was still running after 5 minutes, so for now, all I can say is: try `Plot[Re[Chop[y[x, 100]]], {x, -Pi, Pi} ]`.

Comment: Also, have you tried plotting on smaller ranges? Say, 1 to 1.5: see what this does. Your function might be highly oscillatory, and so the resolution (number of `PlotPoints`) might need to be increased.

Comment: @march plotting takes a while for me as well. But just to be clear - my issue is not just with the plot. I want to be able to do some calculations using `y[x,t]`.

Comment: Well, if it's a problem of resolution in `Plot`, then there might not actually be any problem just using values of `y` in calculations, since you will be plugging in specific numbers. Of course, with complicated expressions such as the output here, sometimes you can run into precision issues, and I'm not an expert in dealing with those kinds of problems.

Comment: @march, thank you for your comments. The problem persists with a different plotting range, so I do not think it is related to `Plot`.

Comment: I have the feeling you have precision issues. Look at the difference when you evaluate `y[1., 100]` vs. `y[1, 100]`. You might consider trying to massage the expression into a simpler form. Otherwise, for now, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Using `c = 4/300` and applying `FullSimplify` to the answer gives a cleaner but still complicated result.  Note that merely plotting `ParabolicCylinderD` with a complex argument is very slow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29734/march) predicted in a comment above, the noise in the plots is a precision issue.  A small improvement can be obtained by setting `c` to a rational number,

```
c = 4/300
```

and applying `FullSimplify` to `y[x, t]`. before plotting.  Nonetheless, even at `t = 0`, the solution is quite noisy.  To illustrate, compare the initial condition on `u` with `y[x, 0]`.

```
p0 = Plot[Cos[Ang[x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
pN0 = ListPlot[Table[Re[y[x, 0] // N], {x, -Pi, Pi, Pi/50}], DataRange -> {-Pi, Pi}];
Show[p0, pN0]
```

[image]

Note that `ListPlot` is used instead of `Plot` to produce results in a reasonable time.  `Plot` is painfully slow due both to the noise and to how slowly `ParabolicCylinderD` evaluates with complex arguments.  (The solution produced by `DSolve` contains several parabolic cylinder functions.)  Even `ListPlot{Table[...]]` takes 17 seconds on my PC.

An obvious course of action is to use higher precision, say `30`.  To do so, use

```
$MaxExtraPrecision = 200;
pN0 = ListPlot[Table[Re[N[y[x, 0], 30]], {x, -Pi, Pi, Pi/50}]
```

Indeed, this eliminates the noise, although the computation now takes 40 seconds.

High precision can, of course, be used with `Plot`, for instance,

```
Plot[Re[N[y[x, 0], 30]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

but remains painfully slow and, moreover, omits a portion of the plot.  On the other hand,

```
DiscretePlot[Re[y[x, 0]], {x, -Pi, Pi, Pi/200}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

produces a good result, although very slowly.

Instead, smooth curves can be obtained reasonably quickly by solving the original equation numerically.

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{u''[t] + (4 (c t - Cos[x])^2 + 4 Sin[x]^2 + I 2 c) u[t] == 0,
   u'[0] == I 2 Cos[x] Cos[Ang[x]] - I 2 Sin[x] Sin[Ang[x]], u[0] == Cos[Ang[x]]},
   u, {t, 0, 100}, {x}]
```

Then,

```
Plot[Re[s[x][20]], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Re[s[x][100]], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

Based on the analysis in my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104629/1063) to a related question, `y[x, 100]` can be plotted with

```
Plot[Re[N[y[Rationalize[x, 0], 20], 30]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
    PlotPoints -> 401, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

to produce the second curve above in about seven minutes (on my PC).  Thus, `NDSolve` remains the function of choice to obtain plots of `y` quickly.

Incidentally, The [Wronskian](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/ParabolicCylinderD/13/01/0002/) of the t-dependent parabolic cylinder functions appearing in `y` is given by

```
(1/5 - I/5) Sqrt[2/3] E^(-(75/2) π Sin[x]^2)
```

Because the Wronskian appears as part of `y`, it is not surprising that very high precision is necessary to obtain accurate values of `y` except for `Sin[x]` near zero.

Answer (score 5):

```
c = 0.01333 // Rationalize;

Ang[x_] = -I Log[-Exp[I x]]/2;

y[x_, t_] =
  FullSimplify[
   DSolveValue[{
     u''[t] + (4 (c t - Cos[x])^2 + 4 Sin[x]^2 + I 2 c) u[t] == 0,
     u'[0] == I 2 Cos[x] Cos[Ang[x]] - I 2 Sin[x] Sin[Ang[x]],
     u[0] == Cos[Ang[x]]}, u[t], t],
   {Element[t, Reals], -Pi <= x <= Pi}];
```

The above definition is in terms of the parabolic cylinder function, [`ParabolicCylinderD`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParabolicCylinderD.html). [`FunctionExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html) can be used to convert to the Hermite polynomial, [`HermiteH`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HermiteH.html)

```
y[x_, t_] = y[x, t] //
    FunctionExpand //
   Simplify[#,
     {Element[t, Reals], -Pi <= x <= Pi}] &;
```

Use the option [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) in [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) to reduce noise in the plot.

```
Plot[Re[y[x, 100]], {x, -Pi, Pi},
 WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image]

Comment: This otherwise creative approach omits a portion of the curve, as can be seen from evaluating `N[y[Pi/2, 100], 30]`.  I encountered the same problem with `Plot[Re[N[y[x, 0], 30]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]`.  Strange.