# Portion of Curve Omitted by Plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, special-functions, complex

In the course of addressing question [104559](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104575/1063), I encountered the following problem with `Plot`.  Begin with

```
c = 4/300;
Ang[x_] := -I Log[-Exp[I x]]/2;
y[x_, t_] = FullSimplify[DSolveValue[
    {u''[t] + (4 (c t - Cos[x])^2 + 4 Sin[x]^2 + I 2 c) u[t] == 0,
     u'[0] == I 2 Cos[x] Cos[Ang[x]] - I 2 Sin[x] Sin[Ang[x]], u[0] == Cos[Ang[x]]},
     u[t], t], -Pi < x < Pi && t > 0];
```

which produces a fairly complicated expression involving multiple instances of `ParabolicCylinderD` with complex arguments.  To plot this function requires a precision  of `30` or so for accuracy, as well as a much higher `$MaxExtraPrecision`. For instance,

```
$MaxExtraPrecision = 200;
DiscretePlot[Re[y[x, 20]], {x, -Pi, Pi, Pi/200}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

produces a well behave plot, although slowly.

[image]

On the other hand, much is missing from (again with `$MaxExtraPrecision = 200`)

```
Plot[Re[y[x, 20]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image]

Neither does the variant

```
Plot[Re[y[x, 20]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 401, MaxRecursion -> 0,
    WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

chosen, to match the `DiscretePlot` as much as possible, produce better results.

What am I missing here?

Comment: On my system (Win7 x64 with MMa 10.3.1) outputs are different: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CiAux.png).

Comment: Please see the screenshot linked in my previous comment.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov  How careless of me.  `$MaxExtraPrecision = 200` is needed.  Please see my edit.

Comment: With `$MaxExtraPrecision = 200` I get the same plots as yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More insight can be obtained by defining

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := Sow[Re[N[y[x, 20], 30]]]
```

and computing

```
Reap[DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, -Pi, Pi, Pi/50}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]]
```

(Only `101` points are computed to save time.), which returns a plot similar to the first one in the question and a `List` of `101` values, each of precision near `30`. On the other hand,

```
Reap[Plot[f[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 101, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 30]]
```

returns a plot similar to the second one in the question and a `List` of `162` items, the first several of which are

```
{0.217995541672468449759129036399, 0.217996, "f[x]", 0.217995541672477047, 
 0.22593380332278834584717, 0.2522593559760361846636, 0.29284359715117881384, 
 0.346538383741713747, 0.41840039473617, 0.49557434541, 0.586051, 
 0.*10^-1, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, ...}
```

(Here `"f[x]"` is meant to represent `f[x]` unevaluated but with precision `30` constants in it.)  Clearly, precision is being lost.  In fact, to obtain a reasonable plot requires `WorkingPrecision -> 120`, which returns a `List` of `106` items, most of which are numbers of precision near `30`.  The third element remains unevaluated.  That Mathematica issues the warning,

```
Plot::precw: The precision of the argument function ... is less than WorkingPrecision (120.`). >>
```

seems not to matter.  I would guess that `DiscretePlot` provides exact values for `x` to `f[x]`, while `Plot` provides values of precision of `WorkingPrecision`.  To reinforce this assessment, note

```
N[Re[y[Pi/2, 20]], 30]
(* -0.566793965421529310188829628517 *)
N[Re[y[N[Pi/2, 120], 20]], 30]
(* -0.56679396542153 *)
N[Re[y[N[Pi/2, 100], 20]], 30]
(* Indeterminate *)
```

**Addendum**

In light of the analysis above, `Plot` can be made to produce a curve like that from `DiscretePlot` by passing rational numbers to `y`.

```
$MaxExtraPrecision = 200;
Plot[Re[N[y[Rationalize[x, 0], 20], 30]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
    PlotPoints -> 401, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

The computation takes about six minutes.

Comment: You also get some wacky results just trying to evaluate `y` for a small set of values:  `ListLinePlot@Re@((N@y[#, -2]) & /@ Range[-3, -2, .05])` - This `ParabolicCylinderD` function must be very hard to implement

Answer (score 3):

Just a comment-with-visuals here.  The problem is evaluating that `ParabolicCylinderD` function.

My thinking is always that you should be able to evaluate a function reliably before you try to plot it.  Also, that plot takes **forever** to evaluate, so I hate to do it and have garbage come back.  So my workflow would be to evaluate the function at a set of points over a small range and try to get *that* right before plotting.

Setting `$MaxExtraPrecision = 200;` didn't have an effect on the following,

```
list = Table[y[x, 20], {x, -3, -2, .02}];~Monitor~x
ListLinePlot[Re@list, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {1, 2}]
```

[image]

How can we get that to evaluate better?  (spoiler: I don't know)  One thought is to rewrite the function in terms of other functions,

```
y2[x_, t_] = FunctionExpand[y[x, t], {x, t} ∈ Reals]
(* (-I 2^(75/2 I Sin[x]^2) E^(-(1/75) I (t - 75 Cos[x])^2)
     HermiteH[-75 I Sin[x]^2, ((1/5 + I/5) (t - 75 Cos[x]))/Sqrt[
     3]] (2^(1/2 - 75/2 I Sin[x]^2) Sqrt[3] E^(75 I Cos[x]^2)
        Cosh[1/2 Log[-E^(I x)]] HermiteH[
        75 I Sin[x]^2, (5 - 5 I) Sqrt[3] Cos[x]] + (15 + 15 I) 2^(
       1/2 (1 - 75 I Sin[x]^2)) E^(75 I Cos[x]^2)
        HermiteH[-1 + 75 I Sin[x]^2, (5 - 5 I) Sqrt[3] Cos[x]] Sin[
        x] Sinh[1/2 Log[-E^(I x)]]) + 
   2^(1/2 (1 - 75 I Sin[x]^2)) E^(1/75 I (t - 75 Cos[x])^2)
     HermiteH[-1 + 75 I Sin[x]^2, -(((1/5 - I/5) (t - 75 Cos[x]))/
      Sqrt[3])] (2^(1/2 + 1/2 (-1 + 75 I Sin[x]^2)) Sqrt[3]
        E^(-75 I Cos[x]^2)
        Cosh[1/2 Log[-E^(I x)]] HermiteH[
        1 - 75 I Sin[x]^2, (-5 - 5 I) Sqrt[3] Cos[x]] + (15 + 
         15 I) 2^(75/2 I Sin[x]^2) E^(-75 I Cos[x]^2)
        HermiteH[-75 I Sin[x]^2, (-5 - 5 I) Sqrt[3]
          Cos[x]] (2 Cos[x] Cosh[1/2 Log[-E^(I x)]] + 
         I Sin[x] Sinh[1/2 Log[-E^(I x)]])))/(2^(
    1/2 + 1/2 (1 - 75 I Sin[x]^2) + 1/2 (-1 + 75 I Sin[x]^2)) Sqrt[3]
     HermiteH[
     1 - 75 I Sin[x]^2, (-5 - 5 I) Sqrt[3] Cos[x]] HermiteH[-1 + 
      75 I Sin[x]^2, (5 - 5 I) Sqrt[3] Cos[x]] + 
   2^(75/2 I Sin[x]^2) E^(-75 I Cos[x]^2)
     HermiteH[-75 I Sin[x]^2, (-5 - 5 I) Sqrt[3]
       Cos[x]] (-I 2^(1/2 - 75/2 I Sin[x]^2) Sqrt[3] E^(75 I Cos[x]^2)
        HermiteH[
        75 I Sin[x]^2, (5 - 5 I) Sqrt[3] Cos[x]] + (15 + 15 I) 2^(
       1 + 1/2 (1 - 75 I Sin[x]^2)) E^(75 I Cos[x]^2)
        Cos[x] HermiteH[-1 + 75 I Sin[x]^2, (5 - 5 I) Sqrt[3]
          Cos[x]])) *)
```

That looks better right?  The Hermite polynomials are well behaved, right?  Well, I've never tried to evaluate one where the first argument is a  complex non-integer.  The plot of this one looks worse,

```
list = Table[N[y2[x, 20]], {x, -3, -2, .02}];~Monitor~x
ListLinePlot[Re@list, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {1, 2}]
```

[image]

Next you could try to do a manual substitution, writing the parabolic cylinder in terms of the Whittaker function,

```
y3[x_, t_] = 
  y[x, t] /. {ParabolicCylinderD[v_, z_] :> 
     2^(v/2 + 1/4) z^(-1/2) WhittakerW[v/2 + 1/4, -1/4, z^2/2]};
list = Table[N[y3[x, 20]], {x, -3, -2, .02}];~Monitor~x
ListLinePlot[Re@list, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {1, 2}]
```

[image]

That's nice, right?  We can plot this function surely,

```
Plot[Re[y3[x, 20]], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

Okay, so I guess not.  The exact same results come when I try to substitute in terms of the confluent hypergeometric series instead.

When it comes down to it, the problem is that the function in the OP is filled with functions like `HypergeometricU[-(75/2) I Sin[x]^2, 1/2, -150 I Cos[x]^2]` or `WhittakerW[1/4 + 75/2 I Sin[x]^2, -(1/4), -150 I Cos[x]^2]`, which oscillate **very** and with **very** high magnitude near `x=Pi/2`, as you can see here

```
{Plot[Re[HypergeometricU[-(75/2) I Sin[x]^2, 1/2, -150 I Cos[x]^2] ], {x, -3, 3}], 
Plot[Re[WhittakerW[1/4 + 75/2 I Sin[x]^2, -(1/4), -150 I Cos[x]^2]], {x, -3, 3}]}
```

[image]

So I reckon that is the problem, you have these very large oscillations which tend to cancel out - and that's hard for numerics to work with.

Comment: At least some of the problems described in your answer are due to inadequate precision.  For instance, `list = Table[N[y[x, 20], 30], {x, -3, -2, 1/50}]; ListLinePlot[Re@list, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {-3, -2}]` produces a smooth curve and no error messages, and `list = Table[N[y[x, 20], 30], {x, -2, -1, 1/50}]; ListLinePlot[Re@list, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {-2, -1}]` does not produce rapid oscillations near `Pi/2`.